# Graphs quasi-isometric to a plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose that a planar graph $\Gamma$ is quasi-isometric to the Euclidean plane. Is it true that the growth function $g(r)$ of $\Gamma$ with respect to any vertex $o$ (that is $g(r)$ is the number of vertices at path distance $\le r$ from $o$) is quadratic? The statement is not true for non-planar graph (take the square grid and replace every vertex by a large full graph).

Comment: I'm sure you can get a counterexample by taking the square grid, and attaching to each vertex randomly one of two distinct finite planar graphs having two distinct numbers of vertices.

Comment: You mean an graph embedded in the plane?

Comment: There are also trivial planar counterexamples (from the standard graph $\mathbf{Z}^2$, add the vertices $(k/3^n,n):1\le k\le 2^n$ and join them to $(0,n-1)$ by a straight edge). So it sounds hopeless unless you require bounded valency.

Comment: OK, Thanks to @LeeMosher and @YCor!  In our case there are no vertices of degree 1 and there are some other conditions.  But it is nice to know that for all plane graphs it is not true.

Comment: @AndreasThom: It does not matter because we are interested in the path metric of the graph.

Comment: Mark, there are no vertices of degree 1 or 2 in my example (the edge between $(0,n)$ and $(1,n)$ has to be replaced by $2^n$ horizontal edges.

Comment: If you want to do only lower bound for degree, then 6 seems to be enough (and trivial) and for 5 there are counterexamples.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Thanks! Our statement: A $(p,q)$-graph ($1/p+1/q=1/2$) is q.i. to $R^2$ if and only if it is flat outside a compact subset. To prove "only if" we have to show quadratic growth  for every $K$-snet of the graph for every $K$. The comments here show that $K=1$ is not enough. 

Since it could be that $p=q=4$, we cannot have any restriction on degrees of vertices except $d\ge 4$.